# Jquery accepting multiple inputs isn't responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make my system which accept multiple Yes/No questions, however, when I try to submit I am getting an error in the console that I am unsure of and nothing is returned from the query. I was previously using an Array while serializing the data but I need to use an Array List now, I have not used jQuery that much and am still unsure of what I am doing wrong. Answers and explanations greatly appreciated. I don't think I am passing the values through correctly but I am not sure how.

Update**
I put one of the rules "Email address required" back into the initial way of doing it and it accepts it. It also shows this decision in the new box. If I select No email required, the checkbox for no in email address shows so clearly it is reading correctly from the database, it's just not sending anything to it. Also when I try and enter a rule using this method it disable the form elements then does nothing.

Current JavaScript

```
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }

$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); } 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
// Variable to hold request
var request;

$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: '300px'});

//$("#distance_slider").slider({});

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#additional_criteria").submit(function(event){

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    //$("#isajax").val("1");    

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serializeArray();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // Fire off each request to /form.php
        for(let oneObject of serializedData){
    $.post({
            url: "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record={RECORD_VALUE}&first_run=1&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1",
            data: oneObject
        })
    }



    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        //console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        //console.log(response);
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Current HTML to send data to the Jquery

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Additional Rules (*Not Required)</button>

<div id="myDIV" hidden="true">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="edit view">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="additional_criteria" name="additional_criteria">

                <table width="100%" border="0" name="additional_criteria">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p><Strong> Additional Rules</strong><p/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">Email Address Required?  </td><td class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" > Yes <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED}>  No <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Do they need to have an account?</td><td class="dataLabel" name="account" id="account" >  Yes  <input type="radio" name="account_c" value="True" {ACCOUNT_T_CHECKED}>  No  <input type="radio" name="account_c" value="False" {ACCOUNT_F_CHECKED}></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Are they subscribed to AWC Newsletter? </td><td class="dataLabel" name="awc" id="awc" >  Yes <input type="radio" name="awc_c" value="True"> No <input type="radio" name="awc_c" value="False"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Do they need to have a mobile?</td><td class="dataLabel" name="mobile" id="mobile"  >   Yes  <input type="radio" name="mobile_c" value="True" {MOBILE_T_CHECKED}>  No <input type="radio" name="mobile_c" value="False" {MOBILE_F_CHECKED}></td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" name="buttonForm" id="buttonForm">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="PopupContactsCriteria"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="query" value="true"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="record" value="{RECORD_VALUE}"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="module" value="{MODULE_NAME}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="{FORM_SUBMIT}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="sugar_body_only" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form" value="{FORM}" />          
                            <input class="button" type="submit" name="addAdditionalButton" id="addAdditionalButton" value="  Add Additional  " />
                        </td>   
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Console Error

```
index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record=a4e26920-e375-42f8-0168-5b63421aa7c7&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1&delete=exclude_awc:237 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record=a4e26920-e375-42f8-0168-5b63421aa7c7&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1&delete=exclude_awc:237)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record=a4e26920-e375-42f8-0168-5b63421aa7c7&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1&delete=exclude_awc:237
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
8jquery.min.js:5 POST http://217.156.214.229/crm/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery.min.js:5
b.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record=a4e26920-e375-42f8-0168-5b63421aa7c7&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1&delete=exclude_awc:228
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: The error is clear: `request` is `undefined`

Comment: And why one separate `$.post()` for every input field?

Comment: @Andreas I get that the error itself is clear I just don't know whats causing the error in the first place! I separate the post for each input field as each one is a separate query and I wasn't sure of another way of doing this?

Comment: _"I just don't know whats causing the error"_ - You haven't initialized a global(?) variable called `request` with anything that would have a `done()` method.

Comment: Sorry didn't show that in the code, I didn't think it was relevant to what I was asking. Find code amended with the request variable shown. It is just a variable used to hold the request

Comment: @Andreas any idea why the variables aren't being put into request?

Comment: ok you're _declaring_ `request` using `var request`, but you aren't _assigning_ anything to it. It doesn't magically get a value all by itself. I assume you want it to be handling responses to AJAX requests...but which of your potentially multiple $.post requests would it be attached to? If you just write `request = $.post...` things are going to get screwy cos of async. BTW your code would be much more efficient if you just sent all the data in one single ajax request.

Comment: @ADyson previously on my system I had it so you used drop down boxes and selected one option at a time. Each option sending a request of to the database, now I need to have these multiple options grouped together so I can select multiple in one go and use one button to send this request. How can I send this off in one ajax request? I don't have much knowledge of this and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: General idea: ditch the `for` loop and do `request = $.post({
            url: "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record={RECORD_VALUE}&first_run=1&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1",
            data: $form.serialize()
        })` ...obviously you also have to amend the PHP to expect to get all the form field values at once. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ - not quite the same as serialiseArray...instead the serialize() method searches within the form and finds all submittable fields by itself

Comment: ...and puts them into form-urlencoded format, just as if you'd submitted the form normally without using AJAX.

Comment: @ADyson The problem is I don't have access to the PHP, so I need to send individual queries the same way as before into the database for results. That's why I have used the loop, sending each one in individually.

Comment: you can't negotiate with whoever maintains the PHP, then?

Comment: @ADyson I can't as I do not have contact with them. It would take to long to get in touch with them about it which is a pain in my ass! Is there no way to maintain the same php and send in multiple queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're *declaring* `request` using `var request;`, but you aren't *assigning* anything to it. It has not been given a value, therefore it's `undefined`. Undefined things don't have functions you can call.

I assume you want it to be handling responses to AJAX requests...but which of your potentially multiple `$.post` requests would it be attached to? If you just write `request = $.post...` and assign all the results to the same variable, it's going to keep overwriting them and likely leave you with only the response to the last call, but in the meantime things could potentially get screwy because AJAX requests are asynchronous. Unlikely, but possible. Either way, it's hopeless because presumably you want the response to all your calls.

So...since your code will generate multiple requests, it makes no sense to have a single variable called `request` and attach the response handlers to it, because it can't handle all the potential requests - instead you can simply attach the handlers directly to each call to $.post().

Get rid of all references to `request` anywhere in your code and then change the latter part to:

```
for(let oneObject of serializedData){
    $.post({
        url: "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record={RECORD_VALUE}&first_run=1&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1",
        data: oneObject
    }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        //console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        //console.log(response);
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }).always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
}
```

You may need to tweak that further so it behaves precisely the way you want (e.g. maybe only re-enabling one input at a time, for instance) but that's a general approach you can take to your scenario.

Comment: Using that, tweaked a bit I still get "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record=a4e26920-e375-42f8-0168-5b63421aa7c7&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1&delete=email:240 The following error occurred: error Not Found"

Comment: well if it's a HTTP status saying 404 Not Found that's not really a code issue, it simply means your URL is wrong. Check the location of index.php relative to the URL where this code is loaded from.

Comment: The URL still works for the previous method, so there is no problem with that. It seems the correct data is not being passed through to the URL causing problems. But , everything is similar to the previous method so I cannot see what is sending the 404 error

Comment: are you sure it works for the previous method? Your previous code (as per the question) wasn't even running, never mind logging errors.

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear, my previous method was to use individual selections, instead of 4 at a time, and it used the same URL and nearly the same javascript and html. This worked, I havn't been able to get this new multi query working at all!

Comment: well, has the PHP code been changed to accept 4 selections at a time instead of 1? If the PHP code is expecting a single value then it won't just magically recognise 4 instead. Or maybe it already allowed it, I don't know - is there a spec? But perhaps it doesn't understand what you're doing, and, rather than the URL being wrong, the PHP is generating this status and sending it back to you. Although it's an odd status to send if there was a validation error, but anyway it's a possibility. It's hard for me to tell - too many pieces of the jigsaw are missing from where I'm sitting.

Comment: All I can do is answer the question in such a way as to fix the thing you asked about, which was the error message. There was enough info in the question to do so, and I've done it, so I'd humbly request that you accept the answer. This 404 error is a different problem, and the material provided doesn't allow me to do much more than speculate about the causes.

Comment: That's fair enough!